# jquery detecting mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem.

The code works fine in Firefox but in Chrome it messes up.

The code is rather basic.
There's a div with a background. Upon jquery's mousedown upon that div I set a function to run at an interval. Upon mouseup the interval is cleared. Simple, right?

So problem is this. Say the user right-clicks in Chrome and brings up the context menu. Or they drag the div. The mouseup event is no longer registered.

Any ideas?

I had an idea where I'd just get the status of the mouse button. But that seems to be impossible to do without a mouse even firing.

```
        function mouseD(e){
            mouseE = e;
            timer = setInterval(scroller, 50);
            $(document).mouseup(function(){
                clearInterval(timer);
            });
            //mouseB = e.button;
            //mouseW = e.which;
            //console.log(e.button + " D " + e.which);
        }
imgbox.mousedown(mouseD);
```

EDIT:
So I managed to solve the context menu and dragging problems by disallowing such acts. The user just can't do it anymore. But if the user right- and left-clicks at the same moment the mouseup never registers.

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this website: it goes into detail about Mouse Events with different browsers.
http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html